# iPhone5 storyboard autolayout

Tags: iphone, ios6, retina-display, autolayout

I am writing an iOS app using autolayout.
I want to place a button at the 30points below from screen Y center.
How can I add constraints for this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://WhatHaveYouTried.com)

Comment: visit this link for [autolayout in ios6.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2)

Comment: I mean constraint in the iOS 6.0 autolayout.

Comment: @Ravindra, I already passed the tutorial before. but I could not find answer about my question in it. Have you found it?

Comment: @JohnSauer Gone through your link, nice article

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *superView = self.view;
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    [button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [superView addSubview:button];

    // adding constraints to the button
    NSLayoutConstraint *cn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:superView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:30];// adds 30 points from Screen Center Y
    [superView addConstraint:cn];


    cn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                         toItem:superView
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                     multiplier:1.0
                                       constant:0.0];// places the button in middle of X axis
    [superView addConstraint:cn];

}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there no way to add this constraint on the storyboard manually?

Comment: Nope. There are many things you can do with the constraint system that IB doesn't provide controls for setting up. This is one of them.